# Contact Support in Indonesia

Tags: contact

I have trouble in using path from ROS. Does ROS have contact support in Indonesia? or someone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to robotics, rizka!

ROS doesn't have support centers. The first step for requesting help is here, on **Robotics Stack Exchange**. The community here is an excellent resource for getting answers and insights from experienced ROS users and developers.

Please check [this checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist) for writing practical, answerable questions. Ensuring your question adheres to these guidelines helps the community understand your issue better and increases your chances of receiving helpful responses.

Good luck!